# can we update signed APK after signed app bundle on Google play store

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I want to update my app on google play store but now I want to upload APK not app-bundle(first time I upload app-bundle(.aab)). is it possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible but first you delete your upload app bundle first.

Comment: Did you try. Does it possible when update app ?

Comment: I did not try, please suggest

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can update it .check original documentation.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

> Prepare your updates
>
> - The package name of the updated APK or app bundle needs to be the same as the current version.
> - The version code needs to be greater than the current version. Learn more about versioning your app.
> - The updated APK or app bundle needs to be signed with the same signature as the current version.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is achievable and it's a straightforward process! Simply go to:

> Your app dashboard > Release Management > App releases

Upload your apk file like you would normally do. When you do this, the aab will be automatically deactivated. Follow all the other regular app-updating guidelines (increment version number, etc) and you'd be good to go.

To learn more about updating your app on playstore, [check this out](https://customersupport.doubledutch.me/hc/en-us/articles/360001395033-Android-How-to-Update-an-App-in-the-Google-Play-Developer-Console).

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible.
First your update is ready then you have to unpublish your app.
Go to your Play Console.Select app. Select Store presence > Pricing & distribution.
In the "App Availability" section, select Unpublish.